Rock paper scissors game keeps printing "invalid choice" even when choice is valid
I know the code is redundant and that it can be made better. My main concern is that my program keeps telling me that I've given an invalid choice even when it is valid since the rest of the program (which only works when the choice is valid) works as well.
    options = ('rock', 'paper', 'scissors')
    opponent_choice = random.choice(options)
    while True:
        user_choice = input('Rock, Paper or Scissors?: ')
        if user_choice not in options:
            print('Invalid choice')
        if user_choice == 'r' and opponent_choice == 'rock':
            print('Tie.')
        if user_choice == 'p' and opponent_choice == 'paper':
            print('Tie.')
        if user_choice == 's' and opponent_choice == 'scissors':
            print('Tie.')
        if user_choice == 'r' and opponent_choice == 'paper':
            print('You lose!')
        if user_choice == 'r' and opponent_choice == 'scissors':
            print('You win!')
        if user_choice == 'p' and opponent_choice == 'rock':
            print('You win!')
        if user_choice == 'p' and opponent_choice == 'scissors':
            print('You lose!')
        if user_choice == 's' and opponent_choice == 'rock':
            print('You lose!')
        if user_choice == 's' and opponent_choice == 'paper':
            print('You win!')


options (which determines whether your program prints out "Invalid Choice") is ('rock', 'paper', 'scissors') but you're testing user_choice against r, p and s.

Note that even if your program prints "Invalid choice" the remaining if statements in the loop still execute. Maybe you want a continue statement after your print statement?

what input you Enter in user_choice ?

Looks like something to close as a typo?  The OP appears to have simply lost track of what input values they're expecting.
